# How to get Cartesian product of two tables in Django Queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is there a way to do the equivalent of a full outer join in Django (I think I've read that full outer joins are not supported).

My scenario is that I have three tables:

*Staff* / *WeekList* / *WeeksCompleted*

The relevant fields I'm trying to work with are:

- *Staff* table - Staff Number.
- *WeekList* table - Week Start date.
- *WeeksCompleted* table - Week Start date and Staff Number.

Basically, everyone should have an entry in the *WeeksCompleted* table (if they're still active, that is, but that's not pertinent for this question). The queryset I would like to produce is a list of Staff who have missing weeks in the *WeeksCompleted* table.

I can get the result I want using SQL queries but it involves a full outer join on the *Staff* and *WeekList* tables. I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this using the queryset functions?

The only other way I can think to do the equivalent of the full join is to create a list using a nested loop of Staff Numbers against each week, which might have a sizeable processing overhead?

**EDIT:** if it helps, here are the three simplified models.

> models.py

```
class Staff(models.Model):
staff_number = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)


class WeekList(models.Model):
week_start = models.DateField(null=True)


class WeeksCompleted(models.Model):
staff = models.ForeignKey(to='weekscompleted.Staff', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
week_list = models.ForeignKey(to='weekscompleted.WeekList', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**EDIT 2:** The join I think I need is:

```
SELECT staff_number, week_start
FROM Staff, Contractor
GROUP BY staff_number, week_start
```

This will give a list of the expected weeks completed for staff:

```
week_start    staff_number
17/10/2020    12345   
17/10/2020    54321
```

I can then compare this to the *WeeksCompleted* table:

```
week_start    staff_number
17/10/2020    12345
```

to find which staff are missing for a week using this query (keep in mind that this is a query I produced in a database):

```
SELECT qryShouldBeCompleted.week_start, qryShouldBeCompleted.staff_number
FROM qryShouldBeCompleted
LEFT JOIN WeeksCompleted ON qryShouldBeCompleted.staff_number = 
WeeksCompleted.staff_number
AND qryShouldBeCompleted.week_start = WeeksCompleted.week_start
WHERE WeeksCompleted.staff_number Is Null
```

This would then produce the result I need:

```
week_start    staff_number
17/10/2020    54321
```

**Edit 3:**

I just found an article on [FilteredRelation](https://sophilabs.co/blog/complex-outer-joins-with-django-filteredrelations) that gets me partway there:

```
Staff.objects.annotate(missing=FilteredRelation('weekscompleted', condition=Q(weekscompleted__week_start='some date'))).values('staff_number', 'missing__staff__staff_number', 'missing__week_start')
```

which gets me this:

```
{'staff_number': '54321', 'missing__staff__staff_number': None, 'missing__week_start': None}
```

The only thing with this is that it only appears to work for one week at a time - using `__lte` in the condition doesn't return any `'None'` values so I'd have to loop through each week...

Comment: It will be helpful if you show your model and sql  query

Comment: You mentioned that sql query worked for you. Could you show that?